# How can i copy text data in a cell to another cell dependent upon a specific text from the same row?

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel sheet I have 5000 rows in 5 columns, A,B,C,D,E.
column A is a 6 digit build number which varies, columns B,C,D,E have a drop down box, which you can select either complete or shortage.

what I am trying to achieve is to copy the specific text(build number) from column A in the various cell to cell H4,I5,J6 etc only when shortages is selected in columns B,C,D,E. and removed from those cells when de-selected from shortage to complete.

see example

```
Trim Shop                   Shortages                           
Seat Build Sequence Log             Build Number                                                        246125 123456                                       

Build Number    Drivers Passengers  Drivers Passengers                                  
246125  COMPLETE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE    SHORTAGE                                    
245874  COMPLETE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE                                    
123456  COMPLETE    SHORTAGE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyvalues()
    For i = 1000
        If Range("B" & i).Value = Shortage or Range("C" & i).Value = Shortage_
                 or Range("D" & i).Value = Shortage or Range("E" & i).Value = Shortage _
                 Then Cell('Enter destination here, by using a formula for i').Value = ("A" & i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula for a conditional copy is straightforward:

```
=IF(B4="SHORTAGE";$A4;"")
```

and gives the following result:

[image]

But it seems to me you have some special requirement about the copy destination (H4, I5, J6) which is not totally clear to me.

Could you better clarify the cell destination criteria?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, the destination cell criteria will show the build number only if the adjacent cells in columns B,C,D,E have shortage irrespective of what row.

Comment: Sorry, it is surely me, but I do not understand. Would you be so kind to make a picture of desired output like the one I did copying manually the origin to destination. Just a small sample for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use 4 more columns to the right of your existing ones the you can input this formula :

`=IF(B5="COMPLETE", "COMPLETE", $A5)`

This assumes your data starts in cell A5 and this formula should be pasted into cell F5, dragged across to I5 and then copied down for however many rows you need.